# XSL - I want to replace all occurrences of an incorrect timezone in my data

Tags: xcode, xslt, maps

I am new to XSL maps. I want to replace all instances of an incorrect timezone. I know the names of the fields that this could happen. There may be some cases where the timezone is correct, so I only ever want to replace +01:00 with +00:00.

Here's what my input looks like (roughly):

```
<WORKORDERSet>
    <WORKORDER>
       <CLIENT_WORKORDER>
        <COMPLETION_SLA_DATE>2017-07-14T10:11:20+01:00</COMPLETION_SLA_DATE>
        <REGION>100000</REGION>
        <RESPONSE_SLA_DATE>2017-07-12T10:11:20+01:00</RESPONSE_SLA_DATE>
        <WO_NUM>W1000669</WO_NUM>
      </CLIENT_WORKORDER>
    </WORKORDER>
    <WORKORDER>
       <CLIENT_WORKORDER>
        <COMPLETION_SLA_DATE>2017-12-14T10:11:20+01:00</COMPLETION_SLA_DATE>
        <REGION>100000</REGION>
        <RESPONSE_SLA_DATE>2017-12-12T10:12:20+01:00</RESPONSE_SLA_DATE>
        <WO_NUM>W1000420</WO_NUM>
      </CLIENT_WORKORDER>
    </WORKORDER>
</WORKORDERSet>
```

Here's what I want my output to look like:

```
<WORKORDERSet>
    <WORKORDER>
       <CLIENT_WORKORDER>
        <COMPLETION_SLA_DATE>2017-07-14T10:11:20+00:00</COMPLETION_SLA_DATE>
        <REGION>100000</REGION>
        <RESPONSE_SLA_DATE>2017-07-12T10:11:20+00:00</RESPONSE_SLA_DATE>
        <WO_NUM>W1000669</WO_NUM>
      </CLIENT_WORKORDER>
    </WORKORDER>
    <WORKORDER>
       <CLIENT_WORKORDER>
        <COMPLETION_SLA_DATE>2017-12-14T10:11:20+00:00</COMPLETION_SLA_DATE>
        <REGION>100000</REGION>
        <RESPONSE_SLA_DATE>2017-12-12T10:12:20+00:00</RESPONSE_SLA_DATE>
        <WO_NUM>W1000420</WO_NUM>
      </CLIENT_WORKORDER>
    </WORKORDER>
</WORKORDERSet>
```

And here's the XSL that I've tried to use but I don't know what I'm doing wrong:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <!-- identity template: copy everything 1:1 -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

    <!--More specific template for Node766 that provides custom behavior -->
    <xsl:template match="WORKORDERSet/CLIENT_WORKORDER/WORKORDER/">  
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <!--Do something special for Node766, like add a certain string-->
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:param name="text"/>
              <xsl:param name="replace"/>
              <xsl:param name="by"/>
              <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$by"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                  <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
                  <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
                  <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sorry for the noob question but any help here is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another option that only processes the text() that contains `+01:00` in elements whos name ends with `_DATE`...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template 
    match="*[contains(concat(local-name(),'|'),'_DATE|')]/text()[contains(.,'+01:00')]">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(.,'+01:00')"/>
    <xsl:text>+00:00</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is perfect for what I need to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should prepare replacing template first to make it dynamic, then match all nodes of CLIENT_WORKORDER - `*[parent::CLIENT_WORKORDER]` to check each of them and replace `+01:00` with `+00:00`, see XSL below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <!--template with value replacing-->
    <xsl:template name="replace-template">
        <xsl:param name="param.str"/>
        <xsl:param name="param.target"/>
        <xsl:param name="param.replacement"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($param.str, $param.target)">                    
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($param.str, $param.target), $param.replacement, substring-after($param.str, $param.target))"/>              
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$param.str"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <!--copy all nodes-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!--take each element of CLIENT_WORKORDER and if it contains +01:00 it will replace it with +00:00-->
    <xsl:template match="*[parent::CLIENT_WORKORDER]">                
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">                    
            <xsl:call-template name="replace-template">                       
                <xsl:with-param name="param.str" select="."/>                       
                <xsl:with-param name="param.target" select="'+01:00'"/>                       
                <xsl:with-param name="param.replacement" select="'+00:00'"/>                   
            </xsl:call-template>               
        </xsl:element>       
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result as expected:

```
<WORKORDERSet>
    <WORKORDER>
       <CLIENT_WORKORDER>
        <COMPLETION_SLA_DATE>2017-07-14T10:11:20+00:00</COMPLETION_SLA_DATE>
        <REGION>100000</REGION>
        <RESPONSE_SLA_DATE>2017-07-12T10:11:20+00:00</RESPONSE_SLA_DATE>
        <WO_NUM>W1000669</WO_NUM>
      </CLIENT_WORKORDER>
    </WORKORDER>
    <WORKORDER>
       <CLIENT_WORKORDER>
        <COMPLETION_SLA_DATE>2017-12-14T10:11:20+00:00</COMPLETION_SLA_DATE>
        <REGION>100000</REGION>
        <RESPONSE_SLA_DATE>2017-12-12T10:12:20+00:00</RESPONSE_SLA_DATE>
        <WO_NUM>W1000420</WO_NUM>
      </CLIENT_WORKORDER>
    </WORKORDER>
</WORKORDERSet>
```

Comment: Thanks that works great for the question that I asked.

Unfortunately the sample I included was pretty poor. There is actually an additional level in the tree.
<QueryResponse>
  <WorkorderSet>
    <Workorder> etc.

The parent call doesn't work when there's an additional level. I am missing something still.

Comment: To clarify; this completely screws it up:
[parent::QueryWORKORDERResponse/WORKORDERSet/WORKORDER/CLIENT_WORKORDER]">

Comment: @Aporia Solution in my answer should work for all elements of CLIEN‌​T_WORKORDER, and it is never mind if it will be /WORKORDERSet/WORKORDER/CLIENT_WORKORDER or /WORKORDERSet/WORKORDER/x/x/x/x/x/x/x/CLIENT_WORKORDER. Mainly to keep that match="*[parent::CLIENT_WORKORDER]"

Comment: You're right. I thought I had tried that initially but didn't look like it was working... I wasn't sure why it wasn't working, but tried again there and it ran no problem. Thanks so much for your answer!

Comment: You can also use `CLIENT_WORKORDER/*` instead of `*[parent::CLIENT_WORKORDER]` (a little shorter/cleaner).